# Is there any way to stop the useEffect infinite loop even after provided with second empty array argument?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux, async-await

I am try to call dispatch method from useEffect hook in my React app but after rendering the useEffect continue looping.
here is my code....

category.actions.js
here is the actions perform

```
import axios from "../../apiFetch/axios";
import { categoryActions } from './constants';


export const getCategories = () => {

  return async (dispatch) => {

    dispatch({ type: categoryActions.GET_CATEGORY_ACTION})

    const res = await axios.get('/category/getCategories');
    console.log(res)

    if(res.status === 200){
      const {categoryList} =  res.data;
      dispatch({
        type: categoryActions.GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
          categories: categoryList
        }
      });
    }else{
      dispatch({
        type: categoryActions.GET_CATEGORY_FAILURE,
        payload: {
          error: res.data.error
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

category.reducer.js
this is reducer code
import { categoryActions } from "../actions/constants";

```
const initialState = {
  laoding: false,
  categoryList: [],
  error: null
}

const categoryReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case categoryActions.GET_CATEGORY_ACTION:
      return{
        loading: true
      };
    case categoryActions.GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
      return{
        loading: false,
        categoryList: action.payload.categories
      };
    case categoryActions.GET_CATEGORY_FAILURE:
      return{
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload.error
      }
    default:
      return{
        ...initialState
      }
  }
}

export default categoryReducer;
```

Category components where I used useEffect hooks

```
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getCategories } from '../../redux/actions';

const Category = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const state = useSelector(state => state.categoryReducer)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCategories());
  },[]);

  return (
    <Layout sidebar>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
              <h3>Category</h3>
              <button>Add</button>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Category;
```

constant.js
here is the constant i used as type

```
export const categoryActions = {
  GET_CATEGORY_ACTION: 'GET_CATEGORY_ACTION',
  GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS: 'GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS',
  GET_CATEGORY_FAILURE: 'GET_CATEGORY_FAILURE'
}
```

here is index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

window.store = store;
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

here is App.js parent component

```
import Signin from './containers/Signin';
import Signup from './containers/Signup';
import PrivateRoute from './components/HOC/PrivateRoute';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { isUserLogin } from './redux/actions';
import Products from './containers/Products';
import Orders from './containers/Orders';
import Category from './containers/Category';


function App() {
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.authReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!auth.authenticate){
      dispatch(isUserLogin());
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/products"  component={Products} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/orders"  component={Orders} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/category"  component={Category} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Check to ensure that `Category` component isn't being remounted. A quick test is `useEffect(() => console.log('Mount'), [])` and if you see a bunch then then the parent component that is rendering `Category` to see why it is remounting children.

Comment: @DrewReese it's only mount once when I inspected the console after rendered e.g it mount once for useEffect(() => console.log('Mount'), []) but infinite loop for useEffect(() => dispatch(getCategories()), [])

Comment: Not that I think this is the issue, but you've a typo in your reducer's initial state, `laoding` vs `loading`. Are you sure it's `Category` that is render looping then? If it's only mounted once it should run the effect only once, and e.g. a single dispatch of `GET_CATEGORY_ACTION`.

Comment: @DrewReese that is why I am here. I have been on this since yesterday. do you need additional info ?

Comment: Could you include the parent component code of `Category`? I really don't see any overt issues the `Category`. Are there any errors? A react crash page with stacktrace? *Some* detail about the render-looping?

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited the post.. you can recheck it. i have added app.js and index.js file

Comment: @DrewReese if I commented all dispatch action method in category.actions.js file and I called axios.get('/category/getCategories') from it, I console.log() the response from api call. there is no infinite loop if I dispatch from Category component useEffect hook. but otherwise there is infinite loop.

Comment: Are you using `redux-thunk` middleware on your redux store?  The action creator `getCategories` is not a pure redux action creator so it will not work if you don't have the right middleware.

Comment: You can add `state`, which is the category data, as a dependency on your `useEffect`.  If categories is something that only needs to be fetched once (something that will not change is response to user actions) then you can make the `dispatch` conditional.  `useEffect( () => { const {loading //fix typo, categoryList, error} = state;  if (categoryList.length === 0 && ! loading && ! error) { dispatch(getCategories); } }, [state])`

Comment: If you don't want to use `redux-thunk`, copy and paste the body of the inner function in `getCategories` into your `useEffect` hook.  Without thunk you can only call `dispatch()` with an action object.

Comment: @LindaPaiste, Thank you very much. I am using redux-thunk and the solution you provided above solve the problem of infinite loop but I get error after after the component render.  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error. for 'categoryList.length' but it always render and dispatch and get API call once before the error emmanate.

Comment: @LindaPaiste, Thank you very much. the soluton you provided really help me but categoryList.length gave an error so I provided another property to state to make it done. useEffect(() => { 
    const { loading, categoryList, error, loaded} = category;
    if( loaded !== true && !loading && !error){ 
      dispatch(getCategories()); 
    } 
}, [category])